# Valuing a game using recursion

Tags: probability, recursion

An urn contains 4 marbles: 2 red and 2 green. You extract them one by one without replacement. If you extract a green marble, I pay you 1 dollar; if you extract a red marble, you pay me $1.25. You can quit playing at any time. Use recursion to value this game from your perspective.

What does it mean to use recursion to value something? How do I go about it?

Comment: I would do this by backwards induction...as it is easy to value the game once most of the marbles have been drawn.  Not sure I'd call that "recursion" however.

Comment: This is on my review sheet for my final exam. I haven't learned anything about induction so I'm not sure that procedure will be allowed when a similar question is inevitably asked.

Comment: What techniques have you learned?

Comment: He used Monte Carlo for recursion, but I was absent that day and there is no textbook

Comment: It's hard to use Monte Carlo to price American options.  Anyway, here it is easy enough to write down all possible paths...there are only six:  $RRGG,RGRG,RGGR,GGRR,GRGR,GRRG$.  the only tricky part is to decide when you exercise the option.  For example:  if you get $G$ first, should you quit instantly? For that matter, can you even prove that the game has positive value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion calls for reducing the problem to simpler problem(s). We might define a function $V(a,b)$ for the value of the game where there are $a$ green marbles and $b$ red marbles.  If you couldn't stop playing, we would have $V(a,b)=\frac a{a+b}(1+V(a-1,b))+\frac b{a+b}(-1.25+V(a,b-1))$.  Each term is of the form chance we drew that color this round times  (payoff this round times plus value of the rest of the game).  As we have the right to quit, if the expected value is negative, we should quit and take zero, so we get $V(a,b)=\max (\frac a{a+b}(1+V(a-1,b))+\frac b{a+b}(-1.25+V(a,b-1)),0)$.  Clearly $V(0,0)=0$ because there is nothing to draw.  This lets you find $V(1,0)$ and $V(0,1)$, then climb the ladder.

Comment: I don't think we should avoid playing.  Half the time you get $G$ first, hence you win $1$.  The other half you can't do worse than playing to the end (a loss of $.5$) so even that crude strategy has a positive expectation.

Comment: Playing right yields a expected pay off of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Note:  I did not vote this down.  I don't understand why anyone would.

Comment: @lulu:  good point.  I deleted the last.  Maybe the downvote came from that.

Comment: I believe in the notes I received from a classmate, you SHOULD play the game but you should employ a certain strategy as given by recursive thinking. I'll upvote and even that unfairness out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @lulu I voted this down, when the answer stated that you should not play the game.

Comment: Wouldn't the ideal strategy for playing correctly be to quit if I pick green immediately (1 profit), play to the end if I pick red twice(0.50 loss), quit if I pick green twice after red (0.75 profit), and play to the end if I pick red then green then red (0.50 loss.)? 

$E[game] = 1*(1/2) + .75(1/6) + .5(2/6) = .458$

If you instead quit with your first green after red, your expected value is $1/3$